# Having glitches when playing video in the browser

Tags: google-chrome, laptop, video

When binge watching on Netflix, the video keep stopped and delayed even though the process bar clearly is ahead of the time.
The weird part is it only happens when the laptop is unplugged. It is not in battery saving mode, and the battery option is fine to me( WiFi adapter and Intel graphic  settings are both in maximum optimization under both the plugged in and on battery mode.
chrome; win10;lenovo yoga 11s.
I am not sure it has something to do with the win 10 thing, since I remember the same thing happened under win 8. But again, it is not my main laptop and I don't use it often, so my memory might be wrong on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this only happens when your laptop is unplugged as you said, it must be energy saving mode issues.

Check if there is any update for your MB BIOS/UEFI / GPU BIOS / GPU Drivers before trying something else.

If it fails, you can try to disable everything about power management is your OS and BIOS (not always possible).

How to disable PCIe Link State Power Management : http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/292971-pcie-link-state-power-management-turn-off-windows.html